# Best way to update DXA to allow for "Build once, Deploy" anywhere pipeline

Tags: dxa, configuration, dxa2.2, spring

TLDR; Essentially we are looking for a way to pass in `spring.profiles.active` JVM option, but not leverage the `dxa.properties` file to do so.

We are working on a DXA app at the moment (2.2 Java) and seem to have discovered a mismatch in intent. The pipeline we are building to auto-deploy for DXA follows a "*Build once, deploy anywhere*" methodology, but the DXA app seems to follow a "*Build once, deploy once*" pattern due to the need to have a few properties set that are specific to environment.

We are trying to allow an environment variable to inject the environment so that DXA will know what properties to grab, but it seems, based on the implementation of the property configurer, it overrides the default Spring implementation of environment injection.

We realise we can use the `dxa.properties` but we'd have to modify the pipeline to be build once, deploy once. The `dxa.properties` allows for setting the `spring.profiles.active` value, but it would **get set to a single value per build**.

We want to be able to pass `spring.profiles.active` value in when we start the JVM so it can be set **dynamically** - is this something anyone has done?

The current alternative is to rebuild part of the pipeline to follow a "build once, deploy once" methodology which we really want to avoid.

Comment: I think we can able to keep the profile in pom.xml and use the maven plugin to keep the properties and web resources for environment-specific configurations and files

Comment: So setting springprofilesactive as an env var on the server running DXA doesnt work for you then?

Comment: Thanks for the comments chaps - I'll revert to the dev team and see if that works too - in the meantime, I believe they set the value in the K8 secrets and then injected it using the annotation @Value("#{environment.secret_name}") on the field in the 2 calsses that needed it.